# Updating an integer defined column in a MySQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table defined like this:

```
create table users (
  id int(10),
  age int(3),
  name varchar (50)
)
```

I want to use a query to update just `age`, which is an integer, that comes from an html form.

When it arrives to the method that updates it, it comes as a string, so I change it to integer with PHP and try to update the table, but it doesn't work

```
$age = intval($age);
$q2 = "UPDATE users SET age='$age'  where username like '$username';";
mysql_query($q2,$con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to cast your `$age` string to an integer.

More importantly, **use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to protect against SQL injection**.

```
$q2 = "UPDATE users SET age = " . mysql_real_escape_string($age, $con)
    . " WHERE name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username, $con) . "'";
mysql_query($q2, $con);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query uses the field `username`, but your CREATE statement says `name`

Also, you should really look into using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection attacks (if someone provides the username `' OR 1=1;--` things are going to break). Finally, is there a reason you're doing `username LIKE '$username'` instead of just `username = '$username'`? If `$username` has no %s in it it amounts to the same thing